# Copying / transferring from one spreadsheet to another code based

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to copy / transfer a sheet from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet. I have tried various methods and .copyTo seems to be the best and most efficient way.

.copyTo works well but I'm struggling to send to a specific sheet...

Here is my code:

```
 function TransferDataOut() {

 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetA = source.getSheets()[0]; //sheet source number  

 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the destination sheet');
 var each = "Data_Incoming"; 

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 sheetA.copyTo(destination); // I tried renaming .setName(each);


 }
```

So if I only use sheetA.copyTo(destination); it simply creates a copy sheet, like Copy of the_souce_sheet_name.
If I try renaming to make it a specific name I will get error after running for the second time that the sheet already exists in destination spreadsheet.

What I really need to achieve is that the function from source spreadsheet copies data from the source sheet to always the same sheet in destination spreadsheet.
Perhaps .copyTo is not the right way to do it?
Any suggestions and code will help please!

The reason for receiving data on a exact sheet in the destination spreadsheet is because I have a trigger On change that executes another script to work with the new incoming data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to overwrite the source sheet of Spreadsheet A to the destination sheet of Spreadsheet B.
- You want to keep the sheet name of `var each = "Data_Incoming"`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? I would like to propose 2 samples. So please select one of them for your situation.

### Sample script 1:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. `each` sheet of Spreadsheet B is deleted.
2. Source sheet of Spreadsheet A is copied to the destination sheet of Spreadsheet B.
3. Sheet name of the copied sheet of Spreadsheet B is modified to `each`.

#### Modified script:

```
function TransferDataOut() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = source.getSheets()[0]; //sheet source number
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the destination sheet');
  var each = "Data_Incoming"; 
  var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName(each);
  if (destSheet) {
    destination.deleteSheet(destSheet);
  }
  sheetA.copyTo(destination).setName(each);
}
```

### Sample script 2:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Copy the source sheet of Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B.
2. If the sheet with the sheet name of `each` is not existing in Spreadsheet B, the copied sheet is renamed to `each`.
3. If the sheet with the sheet name of `each` is existing in Spreadsheet B, the source sheet is copied to the Spreadsheet B as `Copy of ###`.
4. `each` sheet is cleared.
5. All values, formulas and formats of the copied sheet are copied to `each` sheet.
6. Delete the copied sheet.

#### Modified script:

```
function TransferDataOut() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = source.getSheets()[0]; //sheet source number  
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the destination sheet');
  var each = "Data_Incoming";
  var copiedSheet = sheetA.copyTo(destination);
  var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName(each);
  if (destSheet) {
    destSheet.clear();
    var srcRange = copiedSheet.getDataRange();
    srcRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(srcRange.getA1Notation()));
    destination.deleteSheet(copiedSheet);
  } else {
    copiedSheet.setName(each);
  }
}
```

### Note:

- **In this sample script, `each` sheet of the Spreadsheet B (destination Spreadsheet) is deleted. So please be careful this.**

  - So at first, as a test, I recommend to use a sample Spreadsheet.

### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

- You want to run the script of destination Spreadsheet when the source values are copied to the destination Spreadsheet using the script in the source Spreadsheet.

The following sample script is for achieving above situation.

#### Script of destination Spreadsheet:

At first, the script of destination Spreadsheet is prepared.

Script:

```
function doGet() {

  sample(); // This is the function that you want to run when the source values are copied.

  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}
```

After copy and paste above script to the script editor of destination Spreadsheet, please do the following flow.

- Deploy Web Apps.

  1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
  2. Select "Me" for "Execute the app as:".
  3. Select "Anyone, even anonymous" for "Who has access to the app:".
  4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
  5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

     1. Click "Review Permissions".
     2. Select own account.
     3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
     4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
     5. Click "Allow" button.
  6. Copy "Current web app URL:".

     - It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec`.
  7. Click "OK".

#### Script of source Spreadsheet:

As the next step, the script of source Spreadsheet is prepared as follows. In this sample, the sample 2 was used. I think that you can also use the sample 1.

Script:

```
function TransferDataOut() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetA = source.getSheets()[0]; //sheet source number  
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the destination sheet');
  var each = "Data_Incoming";
  var copiedSheet = sheetA.copyTo(destination);
  var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName(each);
  if (destSheet) {
    destSheet.clear();
    var srcRange = copiedSheet.getDataRange();
    srcRange.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(srcRange.getA1Notation()));
    destination.deleteSheet(copiedSheet);
  } else {
    copiedSheet.setName(each);
  }

  // Added
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set the retrieved URL of Web Apps.
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

#### Note:

- By above settings, when `TransferDataOut()` of the source Spreadsheet was run, `doGet()` of the destination Spreadsheet is run by `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: yes you understand correctly, thank you.
I have tried Sample script 1 now. It works as suggested.
Only problem is in destination spreadsheet, after receiving the new data in sheet "Data_Incoming", the trigger in this spreadsheet does not get triggered.
I have tried using On change and also On edit...

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure about the detail of actual destination Spreadsheet, in your case, changing the sheet ID of the sheet of ``Data_Incoming`` might be the reason of the issue. So at first, please back to the situation that the trigger works, and how about using the sample script 2? At the sample script 2, the sheet ID of ``Data_Incoming`` is not changed. If this didn't work, can you provide a sample destination Spreadsheet which is installing the trigger. I would like to confirm your issue.

Comment: the trigger (On change or On edit) in destination spreadsheet also not triggered when trying Sample script 2.
I'm trying the simple On change and On edit triggers.
I don't understand why these triggers does not get triggered when the new data is received in destination spreadsheet ...

Comment: Event: From spreadsheet - On change 
and also tried Event: From spreadsheet - On edit

Comment: `function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Data_Incoming'), true);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('skuif_data')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}`

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the reason of your current issue from your reply comments and script. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to replicate your current issue. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and script for replicating your current issue? If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I think my only question left is what kind of trigger will be triggered in the destination spreadsheet when Modified script 2 has been run from source spreadsheet, and data has been updated in destination spreadsheet? Because I have tried various triggers in destination spreadsheet but nothing seems to pick up the change...

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. You want to run the script of destination Spreadsheet by firing the trigger of the destination Spreadsheet when the sheet of source Spreadsheet is copied to the destination Spreadsheet by running the script of source Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let me best try to explain: Source spreadsheet is triggered every hour and copies data over with Sample script 2 to destination spreadsheet. When this data is received in destination spreadsheet, this should again trigger another trigger that works with data in destination spreadsheet. It seems like On edit and On change is not triggered because data was transferred with a script...

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when the data is modified by the script, OnEdit and OnChange event trigger cannot be fired. This is the specification. But if you want to run the script of destination Spreadsheet when the source values are copied to the destination Spreadsheet using the script in the source Spreadsheet, for example, how about the following workaround?

Comment: @Petrus Deploy Web Apps at the destination Spreadsheet for running the script. When the script of source Spreadsheet is run, it uses Web Apps as the trigger for running the script of destination Spreadsheet. In this case, one function is required to added to the destination side. But at first, I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your situation is correct. How about this, and how about that workaround?

Comment: this sounds like a great idea! Is it possible to help me with this..?

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. I could understand that my understanding was correct. So I added the workaround for using Web Apps. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Great, I will test. Never tried to trigger a script like that before, how interesting!

Comment: Sorry, but how do I then only select a certain  function with the link to a script?

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. You can select the functions using query parameters. If ``https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?key=value`` is used, you can select the script (function) using ``key=value``. I think that this is help to understand about it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script).

Comment: @Petrus Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.